# Ubuntu Touch: kill Windows Manager and start xterm in GUI Mode

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lightdm, xserver

I installed xterm  and I would want it to be the Only GUI application running.
so I killed the lighdm using:

```
sudo service lighdm stop.
```

and try to run xterm using:

```
sudo xterm
```

through a SSH terminal, but I can't run xterm because it says DISPLAY not set up error.

Where is xinit/startx in Ubuntu touch 14.10?

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell your terminal that you want `xterm` to start on the display you are currently sitting in front of. You can do so by typing

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

before you execute `xterm`